# Side Navigation expand collapse icon issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to customize expand and collapse the menu right part icon to the left side but when I put the icon getting blank anyone can help me to solve this issue.

[current demo](http://%20%20%20%20https://codepen.io/blindpiggy/pen/QQzRYY) I need to make this right side icon to left side from this demo

Comment: link not working

Comment: https://codepen.io/blindpiggy/pen/QQzRYY this is the link

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Code relevant to your problem needs to be included directly in your question (in text form & properly formatted), and not just dumped onto some external platform.

Comment: @LaljiTadhani any solution for this?

Comment: Maybe you forget to add "FontAwesome CDN" link

Comment: @SatishModha i have added something is missing see here   https://codepen.io/salman1775/pen/WNREjjG  this demo link also you can't find the icon when you collapse the menu

Comment: Because when you close "Side Navigation" Icons hide in "Left" Side

Comment: https://codepen.io/salman1775/pen/WNREjjG  I have got the solution but only the problem is the mouse hover expand menu not working here like this URL https://codepen.io/sanoobdesign/pen/qBRXmjQ

Comment: anyone can look at this issue?

Comment: codepen.io/salman1775/pen/WNREjjG this solution working fine but now when i expand the menu while mouse hover menu not working properly (jumping to left and right)

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem. You had some issue in the code like:

```
.primary-nav .menu li {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px; // Newly added
}

.menu .icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 10px; // Changed 
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Match this with your code. I have made a fiddle for this. https://codepen.io/salman1775/pen/WNREjjG

Thanks me later.

Comment: when collapse the menu i cant see the icon if i align icon to left side

Comment: even in your https://codepen.io/salman1775/pen/WNREjjG example URL also getting the same issue

Comment: Now check again the same pen. Its working.

Comment: Thanks, @Mohd Salman Problem Solved 
but now the mouse hove expand menu not working  like this pen https://codepen.io/sanoobdesign/pen/qBRXmjQ

Comment: You can achieve that by small js i.e:

$('.menu').hover(function(){
 $("html").toggleClass("openNav");
  $(".nav-toggle").toggleClass("active");
})

Comment: https://codepen.io/salman1775/pen/WNREjjG this solution working fine but now when i expand the menu while mouse hover menu not working properly (jumping to left and right)